# Solving system of linear equations with matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I've got this far and now my question is:  how would i give one particular solution to the system?

Comment: my guess is that there are infinitely many solutions and that giving one particular solution would just be giving any value to the free variables?

Comment: I didnt go all the way to reduced row echelon form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is right.  For instance,  choose $x_2=x_5=1$.  Then $x_3=-1$ and $x_1=2$.  Thus $\begin {pmatrix}2\\1\\-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is a solution.

(Assuming your calculations are correct.)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i think this is it in vector form and to the bottom right is the particular solution?